# CSS how to make 100% height in this case

Tags: html, css

So i have this construction as template, it work fine with full content on page and fork not fine if text or images dont fill all height, then columns and content div look cutted if i color their fields.
index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grad.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div align="center"><img src="img/tsu._e.png" border="0" align="middle"></div> 
    </div>
    <div id="gradient"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content1">
            <div id="content2">
                <div id="content3">
                    <div id="center">

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div id="left"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
html { height:100%; }
body { min-height:100%; position:relative; min-width:800px; }
* html body { height:100%; }
#header { background:#0000FF; height:100px; width:100%; }
#content { width:100%; padding-bottom:60px; width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 805 ? "100%" : "805px"); overflow:hidden; }
#content1 { width:100%; float:left; margin-right:-180px; }
#content2 { background:#000000; margin-right:180px; }
#content3 { width:100%; float:right; margin-left:-200px; }
#left { background:#FFFFFF; width:200px; float:left; }
#center { background:#FFFF; margin-left:200px; }
#right { background:#FFFFFF; float:right; width:180px; }
#min_width { width:800px; }
#footer { position:absolute; bottom:0px; background:#0000FF; width:100%; height:60px; }
```

gradien hight 3px

Question: why div with `id=content` dont fill 100% height? and how repair it in this case?

Comment: possible guidance: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
height:100%;
```

use

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: Please explain why this answers the question. That is, what does the change you suggested do? What effect does it have?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't have 100% in #content

```
#content { width:100%; padding-bottom:60px; width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 805 ? "100%" : "805px"); overflow:hidden;
```

try

```
#content { height:100%; padding-bottom:60px; width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 805 ? "100%" : "805px"); overflow:hidden;
```

and you have all the inner div empty

Answer (score 0):

take of the position relative of your body and give a height: 100% to your content